# Custom UIActivity with custom Data

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

i have some images & text that i want to share via Facebook,twitter ,it works fine , although i want to share another set of data ( activityitems ) with my custom UIActivity

```
 NSLog(@"The Selected Photo Count %i",[self.selectedPhotos count]);

NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *newArraytext=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



for (Shoplog * ChosenPhot in self.selectedPhotos) {

    NSString *initalTextString = [NSString
                                  stringWithFormat:@"I am Sending from my Shoplog Collection: %@",
                                  ChosenPhot.categoryname];

    [newArraytext addObject:initalTextString];
    CreateShoplogTagImage *createimagetag=[[CreateShoplogTagImage alloc]init];
    UIImage *newimage=[createimagetag Imagetag:ChosenPhot];
    NSDictionary *flurrydicttionary3=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:ChosenPhot.categoryname,@"SharedCategoryname", nil];
    [Flurry logEvent:@"SharedCatalogue" withParameters:flurrydicttionary3 timed:YES];
    [newArray addObject:newimage];

}


NSMutableArray *addArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:newArray];
[addArray addObjectsFromArray:newArraytext];


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController2 =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:addArray applicationActivities:@[shopactivity]];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController2 animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass [UIActivityItemProvider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemProvider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or create objects that conform to [UIActivityItemSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Pass in an array of those, and have some of them return nil depending on the chosen activity in the `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` call.